# How to store a table method in a different table?

Tags: lua

I would like to store methods that are associated with a table, so that I can randomly select one of the function using `math.random`. Storing functions in a table and calling those functions is straight forward, as shown below:

```
function funcA()
    print("A")
end

functionTable = {funcA}
functionTable[1]()
```

However, I cannot store a function from a table (a method?) in a new table. The following code will return in an Error (Lua 5.4): *function arguments expected near '}'*

```
local functionStore = {}

function functionStore:funcA()
    print("A")
end

functionStore:funcA()
functionTable = {functionsStore:funcA}
functionTable[1]()
```

I think the colon (:) means that I'm already calling the function?, and then the error would make sense, but I would like to store the function in the table.

What Am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the colon is a special syntactic sugar for function calls to pass the variable / expression preceding it as first argument to the function; it can not be used as an expression. You can however write yourself a function that "curries" the self argument, creating a closure:

```lua
local function curry_self(self, methodname)
    return function(...) return self[methodname](self, ...) end
end
```

then you can use this as follows:

```lua
functionStore:funcA()
functionTable = {curry_self(functionsStore, "funcA")}
functionTable[1]()
```

Alternatively, you may pass `self` as you invoke the function:

```lua
functionStore:funcA()
functionTable = {functionStore.funcA}
functionTable[1](functionStore) -- pass functionStore as `self`
```

In your case, you don't **need the colon at all** though - you don't even use `self` in your function! Thus, you may use:

```lua
local functionStore = {}

function functionStore.funcA()
    print("A")
end

functionStore.funcA()
functionTable = {functionsStore.funcA}
functionTable[1]()
```

you can put functions in a table **without** using the colon, using just the dot to assign them to table fields.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer. Would there also be a possibility to use _G to call the methods by name instead (and then store the names in the table)?

Comment: @Timtico yes, in fact I had considered including it: `local functionStore = {}; function functionStore.funcA() print"A" end; functionNameTable = {"funcA"}; functionStore[functionNameTable[1]]()`. Since you're already storing your functions in a "functionStore" table, you don't need `_G` though?